# Python/Django mime multipart email using boundary

Tags: python, django, email, multipart, boundary

In Django(with python), how can I build an email that looks as follows:

What I need is an e-mail that starts with:

```
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
boundary="=_5f8686714d769f9476ce778798b84ff4"
```

The boundary is the place to put plain text:

```
--=_5f8686714d769f9476ce778798b84ff4
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="ISO-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

This e-mail is in HTML-format. Click the following link: 

 http://www.company.nl/enews/7
--=_5f8686714d769f9476ce778798b84ff4
```

After that I need an related Content-Tye:

```
Content-Type: multipart/related;
boundary="=_e49477d06c604958b9b2bc038628a26f"
```

The boundary is the place to put the html

```
--=_e49477d06c604958b9b2bc038628a26f 
Content-Type: text/html; charset="ISO-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.= w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> <html style=3D"height: 100%"> <head>/head> <body></body> </html>
--=_e49477d06c604958b9b2bc038628a26f
```

Eventually it would look like this:

```
Received: (qmail 6116 invoked by uid 48); 16 Jul 2012 18:00:49 +0200
Date: 16 Jul 2012 18:00:49 +0200
To: my@email.nl
Subject: Something
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: Company <company@company.nl>

Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="=_5f8686714d769f9476ce778798b84ff4"
Message-ID: <m79ghd.ezdd6g@company.nl>

--=_5f8686714d769f9476ce778798b84ff4
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="ISO-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

This e-mail is in HTML-format. Click the following link: 

 http://www.company.nl/enews/7
--=_5f8686714d769f9476ce778798b84ff4

Content-Type: multipart/related;
    boundary="=_e49477d06c604958b9b2bc038628a26f"

--=_e49477d06c604958b9b2bc038628a26f
Content-Type: text/html; charset="ISO-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.=
w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html style=3D"height: 100%">
<head>/head>
<body></body>
</html>
--=_e49477d06c604958b9b2bc038628a26f
```

I tried this with Django's EmailMessage(Alternatives), python MimeMultipart but I can't get it in the exact order.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to send a plain text and HTML version of an e-mail (where the plain text version just refers to an URL), the [EmailMultiAlternatives](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types) class seems to work fine for me.

A slightly modified version of the example from the docs:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

subject, from_email, to = 'hello', 'from@example.com', 'to@example.com'
text_content = 'This e-mail is in HTML-format. Click the following link:\n\nhttp://www.company.nl/enews/7'
html_content = '<p>This is an <strong>HTML-format</strong> version.</p>'
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
msg.send()
```

Results in this email (using the [console backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/email/#console-backend)):

```
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="===============2514609180855632526=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
Subject: hello
From: from@example.com
To: to@example.com
Date: Wed, 18 Jul 2012 10:31:22 -0000
Message-ID: <20120718103122.11355.59803@localhost6.localdomain6>

--===============2514609180855632526==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

This e-mail is in HTML-format. Click the following link:

http://www.company.nl/enews/7
--===============2514609180855632526==
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>This is an <strong>HTML-format</strong> version.</p>
--===============2514609180855632526==--
```

While it does not have the `multipart/related` Content-Type, it does work both on plain text (showing the link) and HTML clients (showing the HTML version).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [email](http://docs.python.org/library/email.html#module-email) and [smtplib](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html) modules directly.

Django built-in methods for email handling are very limited.